# Tree identification Washington State

Tags: fruit-trees, cherries, plums

Tree Identification. Any ideas what this is? They emerged red. I feel like it's way too early for them to be cherry and way to small for them to be plums? And they don't look like cherry plums either. Will they get bigger maybe? I can't find any pictures or videos of young plums to compare. 
[image: Full Tree]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like Myrobalam Plum.  Looked forward to visiting homes with these trees.  Yummm. 
[Myrobalam Plum Pictures](https://images.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search;_ylt=AwrTccODHUNZ6Z4A2mknnIlQ;_ylu=X3oDMTByNWU4cGh1BGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNzYw--?p=Myoblan%20Plum&fr=yhs-mozilla-002&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-002)  I know Washington very well; coast, middle and far east.  This is a very common tree.  Sort of 'weedy', tons of suckers, but amazingly reliable for shade and this...cherry like plum.  Yumm.  See what you think of the pictures I've sent.

Comment: After it fruited we came to find out you were correct. It was a Myrobalam plum! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, thank you for letting us know!  Lucky, you!

Answer (score 4):

It seems a wild *Prunus domestica* (plum).  "Wild" this time means probably grown by core of cultivated plums (or just few generation from such cultivated plum).

I have several of this "wild" varieties, and one is very dark and branches and leaves redish.  Unfortunately I never get ripe fruits.

But to be sure, did you remember the flowers? I would expect them from white to dark pink.

Doesn't eat the fruits until you have a definitive identification.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I honestly don't remember it blooming. We just moved in April so it may have bloomed prior. Either that or I was really focused on the huge beautiful cherry tree that blossomed next to it.

Comment: What are some examples of trees that look like plum or cherries but arent?

Comment: Prunus (name given by Plum) has a huge variety of species and varieties. Some cultivated for flowers and some for fruits (plums, cherries, peaches, nectarines, apricot, almond, ..), and the same family (Rosaceae) has much more (forgetting apples and pears), we have e.g. _Sorbus_, a very diverse genre and I think some fruits are poisons. Additionally fruits are similar to other families (e.g. Cornus).  Because US has much much more tree species than Europe, I would not make a bet.  You need to search online for "our" species, and check if your tree has all other characteristics (not in photo).

Answer (score 1):

If it has one seed in the center then its a Prunus, if it has multiple seeds in threes/fives or more then its a Malus. the leaves to me say the later, but the fruit says the former.